# Extract only subpages with Scrapy's LinkExtractor

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl the website http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/, which lists houses for sale in Amsterdam, and extract data from the subpages such as http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801360-brede-vogelstraat-2/ for individual houses. As a first step, I would first like to get a list of all these subpages. So far, I have the following spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from Funda.items import FundaItem
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response

class FundaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Funda"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/"]

    le1 = LinkExtractor(allow=r'%s+huis-\d{8}' % start_urls[0], allow_domains='funda.nl')
    rules = (
    Rule(le1, callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        links = self.le1.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            item = FundaItem()
            item['url'] = link.url
            print("The item is "+str(item))
            yield item
```

If I run this generating JSON output as `scrapy crawl Funda -o funda.json`, then the resulting `funda.json` looks like this (the first few lines only):

```
[
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801360-brede-vogelstraat-2/ywavcsbywacbcasxcxq.html"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801360-brede-vogelstraat-2/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801360-brede-vogelstraat-2/print/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801360-brede-vogelstraat-2/reageer/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801360-brede-vogelstraat-2/bezichtiging/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801360-brede-vogelstraat-2/brochure/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801360-brede-vogelstraat-2/doorsturen/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801360-brede-vogelstraat-2/meld-een-fout/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49800159-breezandpad-8/ywavcsbywacbcasxcxq.html"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49800159-breezandpad-8/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49800159-breezandpad-8/print/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49800159-breezandpad-8/reageer/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49800159-breezandpad-8/bezichtiging/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49800159-breezandpad-8/brochure/download/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49800159-breezandpad-8/doorsturen/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49800159-breezandpad-8/meld-een-fout/"},
```

In addition to the desired subpages `http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801360-brede-vogelstraat-2/` and `http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49800159-breezandpad-8/`, there are also many 'sub-subpages' which I didn't intend to select. How might I only select the subpages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I've added an `if` statement which checks that the `url` has the desired number of forward slashes (6) and ends with a forward slash:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from Funda.items import FundaItem
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response

class FundaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Funda"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/"]

    le1 = LinkExtractor(allow=r'%s+huis-\d{8}' % start_urls[0])
    rules = (
    Rule(le1, callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def house_link(link):
        url = link.url
        return url.count('/') == 6 and url.endswith('/')

    def parse_item(self, response):
        links = self.le1.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            if link.url.count('/') == 6 and link.url.endswith('/'):
                item = FundaItem()
                item['url'] = link.url
                print("The item is "+str(item))
                yield item
```

Now the JSON file generated by `scrapy crawl Funda -o funda.json` has the desired limited number of URLs:

```
[
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49879212-henri-berssenbruggehof-15/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49713458-jan-vrijmanstraat-29/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49728947-emmy-andriessestraat-374/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49800159-breezandpad-8/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49818887-markiespad-19/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801593-jf-berghoefplantsoen-2/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49890140-talbotstraat-9/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49805292-nieuwendammerdijk-21/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801910-claus-van-amsbergstraat-86/"}
][
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49713458-jan-vrijmanstraat-29/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49701161-johannes-vermeerstraat-16/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49879212-henri-berssenbruggehof-15/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49728947-emmy-andriessestraat-374/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801593-jf-berghoefplantsoen-2/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49800159-breezandpad-8/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49805292-nieuwendammerdijk-21/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49890140-talbotstraat-9/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49801910-claus-van-amsbergstraat-86/"},
{"url": "http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/huis-49818887-markiespad-19/"}
]
```

I'd welcome more elegant solutions! It would seem to me that determining link depth from a URL is such a common task that there are already methods/modules for it.